# VS Code is pointing me to an early JDK version

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I created a folder and opened it in VS Code.

I made a java file in it

VS Code says I should use JDK 11

[image]

When I click the link it goes to  https://developers.redhat.com/products/openjdk/download?sc_cid=701f2000000RWTnAAO

I don't know if there is any advantage over redhat vs sun.

The red hat site lists 
VS Code is pointing me to an early JDK version

The red hat site has a red download button, and below it lists a bunch of java versions starting from Java 8(i.e. 1.8), which is a bit old.

[image]

If I click the red download button then it downloads

https://developers.redhat.com/download-manager/file/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.252-2.b09.redhat.windows.x86_64.zip

I understand that Oracle JDK (previously Sun JDK) is the original.

I guess I could download Red Hat Java JDK, but why is VS Code and Red Hat website pointing me to Java 8, which is old?

I did install Oracle or Sun Java 8 because I needed appletviewer.exe so I needed  something old eg java 10 or java 8, so as to include that. But now I have it I can install a later JDK version.

I'm wondering what setting is VS Code seeing that is causing it to try to get me to download JDK 8, when A) it's old b)I already have it C) initially I clicked to install JDK 11. D) The latest JDK looks like JDK 14

Comment: You need to ask one question at a time. Read [Java is Still Free](https://medium.com/@javachampions/java-is-still-free-2-0-0-6b9aa8d6d244) and understand that if you're using Oracle's JDK, you have already agreed to some fairly draconian licensing terms ($$$$ in production). JDK 8 and JDK 11 are long term support releases of Java. JDK 14 is not. Applets are dead. Good luck!

Comment: Java 8 is still popular because a great many libraries use unauthorized hacks which will not work in Java 9 and later, thanks to an enhanced security model.  People who based their applications on those libraries are forced to stick with Java 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter with vscode, the redhat website shows this. You can download any versions you like, which just a little below of the page.

Only the jdk8 and the jdk11 are the LTS(Long Term Support release), and the next LTS is jdk17 in 2022.

You can also refer this page: [Why is OpenJDK 8 supported for longer than OpenJDK 11](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4934371)